# getting between dates in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I am able to fetch values for :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ATTENDANCE_DATE < SYSDATE;
```

but no records for

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ATTENDANCE_DATE between SYSDATE and SYSDATE -20;
```

what is wrong in this?

Comment: what is the datatype of `attendance_date`?

Comment: [From the docs: If *expr3* < *expr2*, then the interval is empty.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions011.htm)

Comment: Also remember that `SYSDATE` has a time component, so if you are running the query at 2:00pm, `SYSDATE - 20` will also be from 2:00pm. Often when checking days you will want to use: `WHERE attendance_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 20) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)`

Comment: using TRUNC, a great tip. Thanks Glen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you re-write the second where clause to what it means, it's obvious.

The expression `between SYSDATE and SYSDATE -20` is equivalent to:

```
where ATTENDANCE_DATE >= sysdate and ATTENDANCE_DATE <= sysdate - 20;
```

What you mean is:

```
where ATTENDANCE_DATE between sysdate - 20 and sysdate;
```

---

Theoretically the SQL standard defines the `symmetric` option for between which allows any "order" of values, so that the following would do what you want:

```
between symmetric SYSDATE and SYSDATE - 20
```

But unfortunately Oracle does **not** support this.

Comment: Unfortunately Oracle does not support `symmetric `.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: that's what I wrote.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I see. +1

Answer (score 3):

Your where condition is always false. You need to change the order.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE ATTENDANCE_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE - 20 AND SYSDATE;
```